# Числительные перед словом «сутки»

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Завис я на фразе **полтора** (полторы?) **суток**. Как вообще правильно употреблять числительные по отношению к слову "сутки"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

В сочетании **по́лтора суток**, где слово "сутки" стоит в форме родительного падежа множественного числа, у числительного смещено ударение.
◆ По́лтора суток без перерыву лил дождь. Шоссейная дорога стала, как в весеннюю распутицу. М. М. Пришвин, «Лесная капель», 1943 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка).

А в общем грамота поясняет:
http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters?rub=rubric_92

«Полтора суток» или «полторы сутки»?
Грамматически сочетание *полтора суток* небезупречно: в именительном падеже количественное числительное "полтора" управляет существительным в единственном числе (полтора метра, полтора часа). Но в литературном языке выражение *по́лтора суток* (но не *полторы суток*) существует.
Т. к. слово "сутки" не имеет формы единственного числа, то заданный смысл рекомендуется выражать описательно, например: в течение полутора суток, полтора дня (если точное значение слова сутки не принципиально).
С существительными, не имеющими формы единственного числа, следует употреблять слово "полутора": *Не прошло и полутора суток. Время ожидания приближается уже к полутора суткам. Все ограничилось полутора сутками.*